How many API transactions a year is an acceptable limit?
I have been told that an application we are working with cannot integrate with another application by polling for information every 5 minutes as they have a 'transaction limit' of 100,000 a year.
I am not a developer by any means, and don't understand what a transaction limit is, or if these are easy to change. Could someone shed some light on this in layman's terms, thanks!

Your internet has a download limit. Once you've exceeded your monthly limit, your access provider will stop you from downloading data. The application with a transaction limit will stop sending you responses (or will respond with errors) if you send more than 100 000 requests in a year. You might be able to pay the provider to accept more transactions per year. I don't know that this is a StackOverflow question.
